# Add NIR information to ALS point cloud

Tags: lidr, rgb

I need to merge Red-Green-Blue_NearInfrared (RGBI) information to pointclouds and I am doint it in R with the package `lidR` version 4.0.2.

I made this small example case to show my error and questions:

```
# Read las
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)

# Generate dataframe with random RGBI values
rgbi=data.frame(Red=  as.integer(sample(seq(from=0,to=100,by=5),size=nrow(las@data),replace=TRUE)),
                Green=  as.integer(sample(seq(from=0,to=100,by=5),size=nrow(las@data),replace=TRUE)),
                Blue=  as.integer(sample(seq(from=0,to=100,by=5),size=nrow(las@data),replace=TRUE)),
                IR=as.integer(sample(seq(from=0,to=100,by=5),size=nrow(las@data),replace=TRUE)))

# First add rgb values with the existing command 
las = add_lasrgb(las, rgbi$Red, rgbi$Green, rgbi$Blue)
las$B[1:6]
rgbi$Blue[1:6]
# > las$B[1:6]
# [1] 14135     0 20560 14135 20560 16705
# > rgbi$Blue[1:6]
# [1] 55  0 80 55 80 65

# Add NIR values
las = add_lasattribute_manual(las.rgb, rgbi$IR, name="NIR", desc="NIR",type="float")
# Error: NIR is part of the core attributes and is a forbidden name.
```

In the description for `add_attribute()` it says *"These functions are dedicated to adding data that are not part of the LAS specification. For example, add_lasattribute(las, x, "R") will fail because R is a name reserved for the red channel of a .las file that contains RGB attributes. **Use add_lasrgb instead**."*

However, there is not a function to add NIR information as there is for RGB. Is there another way of storing this information? I tried `add_lasattribute_manual()` as suggested [here](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/issues/659) but it retrieves the error that says NIR is a forbidden name.

Also, RGB values are not stored as they are indicated. I guess it has to do with some scaling but I dont understand what is being done and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no `add_nir`. This could be added. You can simply force the addition of the column by by-passing control implemented in `lidR`

```r
las@data$NIR = IR
```

One reason there is a function `add_lasrgb` in mainly because the point cloud format must updated if you want to write it in a LAS file. Your point format is `1` at the begining. Then you used `add_rgb` so the format becomes `3`. To write a valid LAS file with RGB and NIR the format must be 8 (no other option)

```r
las@header@PHB[["Point Data Format ID"]] <- 8L
```

`add_nir()` would look like (with some extra control to ensure the validity of the data)

```r
add_lasnir <- function(las, NIR)
{
  las@data$NIR <- NIR
  las@header@PHB[["Point Data Format ID"]] <- 8L
  return(las)
}
```

---

> Also, RGB values are not stored as they are indicated. I guess it has to do with some scaling but I dont understand what is being done and how to avoid it.

RGB are scaled and recorded on 16 bits as required by the specifications. This is what is written in the LAS specifications

> Note that Red, Green, Blue and NIR values should always be normalized to 16 bit values. For example, when encoding an 8 bit per channel pixel, multiply each channel value by 256 prior to storage in these fields. This normalization allows color values from different camera bit depths to be accurately merged

---

**Edit:** I added a function `add_lasnir()` in v4.0.3

Comment: When running the new ```add_lasnir()``` function on the example I see that it does not make any changes to the NIR values as ```add__lasrgb()``` does to RGB values. Shouldn't they be normalized as well?

Comment: Also, as it says in the LAS specifications to multiply by 256 each of the RGB channels, if I multiply for example ```rgbi$Blue``` values by 256, they are not equal to ```las$B```. Shouldn't they be the equal? I havelook into the ```add_lasrgb``` funtion and I think it multiplies by 257, is this correct?

Comment: This is correct, lidR multiplies by 257 such as 255 <-> 65535. The function `add_nir()` in my example does not scale. The [new function in 4.0.3](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/blob/master/R/add_attribute.R#L221) does it.

Comment: I can confirm it is working in lidR 4.0.3, thanks. I still dont understand why is multiplying by 257 and not 256 though.